# Arrays decaying into pointers

Tags: c

Please help me understand the programs below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[7];
    a[0] = 1976;
    a[1] = 1984;
    printf("memory location of a: %p", a); 
    printf("value at memory location %p is %d", a, *a); 
    printf("value at memory location %p is %d", &a[1], a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

`&a[1]` and `&a+1`. Are they same or different?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{
    int v[10];
    int **p; 
    int *a[5];
    v[0] = 1234;
    v[1] = 5678;
    a[0] = v; 
    a[1] = v+1;
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", *a[0],*a[1],a[0][0],**a);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(v));
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to know how `*a[5]` is represented in memory. Is `*a` a base pointer that points to `a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]`?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int v[10];
    int **p;
    int (*a)[10];
    a=&v;
    printf("%d\n",*a);
        return 0;
}
```

`a=v; // gives error why?` does `v` here decay into `*v`. Then does `&v` get decayed into `(*)[]v`? & means const pointer. Here, how is it possible to set a const pointer to a non-const pointer without a typecast?

Where does the array get stored in the memory. Does it get stored onto the data segment of the memory.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int carray[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d\n",carray[0]);
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",sizeof(carray),sizeof(&carray),sizeof(&carray[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

**EDITED:**

I have gone through some of the articles which stated that the only two possible situations where an array name cannot be decyed into pointer is the `sizeof` and `&`. But in the above program `sizeof(&carray)` gives the size as 4. and `&carray` decays into `(*)[]carray` as its an rvalue.

Then the statement that array name cannot get decayed into pointers on two conditions `sizeof` and `&` becomes false here.

Comment: To print a value of type `size_t`, such as the result of `sizeof`, either use `%zu` (if your compiler supports it) or convert the value to some other type and use a format appropriate for that type.  `%d` requires an argument of type `int`, and can fail badly if you give it a `size_t` argument.  To print a pointer value, you must convert the value to `(void*)` and use `%p`; different pointer types are not generally compatible.  Example: `printf("obj has size %lu and address %p\n", sizeof obj, (void*)&obj);`

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).  Understand that arrays and pointers are two *very* different things; do not listen to anyone who tries to tell you that they're equivalent.

Comment: @Keith:Thanks keith.Will read those sections.

Comment: "But in the above program  `sizeof(&carray)` gives the size as 4. and `&carray` decays into `(*)[]carray` as its an rvalue." No, it does not decay. The result of the address-of operator is *always*, well, an address. That is, while `carray` is an array, `&carray` is its address. An address on your machine is, perhaps disappointingly, only 4 bytes long. Consequently, `sizeof(&carray)` yields the address size, 4. No decay is involved. I'm fairly sure that `sizeof(*&carray)` yields 20, showing that the array size was perfectly well preserved through the back and forth.

Answer (score 5):

> `&a[1]` and `&a+1`. Are they same or different?

Different. `&a[1]` is the same as `(a+1)`. In general, `x[y]` is by definition equivalent to `*(x+y)`.

> I wanted to know how `*a[5]` is represented in memory. Does `*a` is a base
>   pointer that points to `a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]`.

In your second example, `a` is an array of pointers. `*a[i]` is the value of the object, the address of which is stored as the i<sup>th</sup> element in your array. `*a` in this case is the same as `a[0]`, which is the first element in your array (which is a pointer).

> `a=v //why this gives error`

Because `a` (in your last example) is a pointer to an array. You want to assign to `a`, then you need to assign the address of the array `v` (or any other array with correct dimensions);

```
a = &v;
```

This is very good that you've commited to understanding things, but nothing will help you better than [a good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Stuff you are gonna need to know when dealing with pointers is that:

```
int *a and int a[]
```

is a declaration of an Array, the only diffrence is that in a[] youre gonna have to declare its constant size, *a gives you flexability, it can point at an array size 1 to infinity

```
int *a[] and int **a
```

is a declaration of an Array of Array,sometimes called Matrix, the only diffrence is that in *a[] youre gonna have to declare how many Arrays a[] gonna contain pointers of, **a gives you flexability, it can point at any Array of arrays that you want it to be assigned to.

IN GENERAL:
    When adding & to a variable, your adding a * to its Type definition:

int a;

&a -> &(int)=int*

when adding * to a variable, you decrase a * from its Type definition

int *a;

*a -> * (int * )=int

```
int *a;
&a - the Address given to the pointer a by the system(pointer of pointer = **a)
&a+1 - the Address to the beginning of the array + 1 byte
&a[1] == &(a+1) - the Address to the beginning of the array + 1 size of int

int **a;
*a == a[0] - the Address of the first Array in the array of arrays a
*a[0]==a[0][0] - the first int of first array

int *a, b[5];
*a=*b - ERROR because a points at garbage to begin with
a=b - a points at array b
```

ask me what else you want to know and ill edit this answer.

Comment: `int *a` declares a pointer object; it does not declare a pointer object.  `int a[]` declares an array object; it does not declare a pointer object.  Arrays are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: you can declare int a[] and int *b and have a command like b=a and a=b is what i meant, you can go ahead and try it.

Comment: I suggest you try it.  If you declare `int a[]` *as a parameter*, then it's really a pointer declaration, not an array declaration.  In any other context, `int a[]` or `int a[N]` declares `a` as an array, and an array name cannot appear on the left side of an assignment.