# When to use a &?

Tags: c, scanf

Why scanf requires a & for int but none for a char?

```
  int main ()
     {
        char str [80];
        int i;

        printf ("Enter your family name: ");
        scanf ("%s",str);  
        printf ("Enter your age: ");
        scanf ("%d",&i);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Search for "array pointer decay" for why using `str` as a scanf argument works without an `&`. It could also be written as `&str[0]` (which also means "the pointer to the first element", but said more explicitly). Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378555

Comment: Just remember that the address-of operator (`&`) results in a pointer, so `&some_char_array` returns a `char (*)[80]`, i.e., a pointer to array of 80 char.  Not what you wanted.

Comment: "Why scanf requires a & for int but none for a char?" - it does require `&` for a char too. But you don't have a char, you have a whole **array** of them.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` requires a pointer (memory address) where it scans data into.  Although `str` is an array of characters, when `str` is used in an expression (e.g. as an argument to scanf) it actually means the memory address of its first element.  For an `int`, however, you have to explicitly tell `scanf()` to use its memory address, which is why you use the `&` (address-of) operator.

Answer (score 1):

becase is `str` a address of the array's fisrt item while `i` is only the name of int, `&i` means the address of `int i`

Answer (score 1):

Standard library function `scanf()` expects a pointer corresponding to the data you want to read. So you are always required to pass a pointer.

In case of `char[]`, the array name decays into a pointer to the first element of the array, which is why you don't use `&` for char arrays. In fact, using an ampersand (`&`) for a char array when passing to scanf(), is wrong as the type of `&charArray` is `char (*)[N]` whereas scanf() expects a `char*` for the format specifier `%s`.

In case if you have pointers, then you can simply pass them directly. E.g.

```
int *p;
char *c;
p = malloc(sizeof(int)); // one int
c = malloc(100); // 100 bytes  
scanf("%d%99s", p, c);
```

As said above, you don't use `&` here as the arguments are already pointers and using `&` is wrong as that will make them pointer to pointers.

So you use `&` whenever the argument to scanf() is not a pointer to an object of the type you want to read in.

Answer (score 0):

`str` decays to a pointer because it's an array (therefore it points to its first element, this does **not** mean that arrays and pointers are the same thing). `i` requires `&` because `scanf` needs the address where to store the value, so it needs the address of `i`.