# How to return a pointer to an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm writing a function which is to read in a file and insert the text character by character into an array, and then return a pointer to that array. The max size permitted for the file is supposted to be 2KB.

Here's what I have now:

```
int main(){
    char data[2048];
    char* data4=layer4(data);
}

char* layer4(char array[]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("sendfile.txt","r+");
    fscanf(fp, "%c", array);
    for(int i=0; i<2048; i++){
        printf("%c\n",array[i]);
    }
    return &array;
}
```

Comment: Why? what you want to achieve by returning?

Comment: The array is going to be used in other function calls to come.

Comment: @freelancer05: you needn't return the array, the main knows about it, and it's modified in-place.

Comment: @freelancer05, don't believe the answers below. They are not going to help you, as the problem you have is not in returning something, but first reading into something.

Comment: Why are you reading just 1 character from the file, then printing 2048 characters from the array? All but the first of them are uninitialized.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why does `strcpy()` need to return its first argument?

Comment: @Barmar: possibly because it allows to nest several calls, like strcpy(a, strcpy(b, c)). But it needn't do it as the returned value is the value passed.

Comment: @Barmar, why this function needs to return pointer is the problem. If you have question about strcpy, create a new post about it, or write to ANSI-C committee to change it.

Comment: @JayKumarR That was a rhetorical question. My point is that it's reasonable for a function to return a pointer even when it's the same as the argument, because `strcpy()` is a model to emulate.

Answer (score 6):

You only need to return:

```
return array;
```

Comment: But note that it isn't a pointer to an array, it is a pointer to `char`. The distinction is important.

Comment: surprised how this wrong answer gets 3 '+' or 'ups'. The OP has no loop reading the file, scanf will read always into first element of the array. As Sourav Gosh pointed out, there is nothing to return anyway as parameter has the same pointer as return value.

Comment: @Jay Kumar R  `strcpy()` and many standard functions return the same pointer.   Should the function return the value or not isn't OP's central issue.

Comment: @chux, exactly. Why do you talk about returning the value, while the code has not read more than 1 char from the file? Why everyone answers return value when central issue is something else?

Comment: @Jay Kumar R I mentioned the return value as a  comment to [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302052/how-to-return-a-pointer-to-an-array-in-c/35302076?noredirect=1#comment58314504_35302076) that mentioned the return value.  Sounds like we agree the key issue is not the return value.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple problems.  Some implied by [@Jay Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302052/how-to-return-a-pointer-to-an-array-in-c/35302472#comment58314613_35302052)

```
char* layer4(char array[]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("sendfile.txt","r+");

    // check if open succeeded
    if (fp == NULL) return NULL;   

    // Unclear why codes read only 1 char
    // fscanf(fp, "%c", array);
    // Suspect OP wants
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i<2048; i++){
      if (fscanf(fp, "%c", &array[i]) != 1) break;
    }
    // Could have use fread()

    // More canonical to use type `size_t` than `int` to index arrays.
    // for(int i=0; i<2048; i++){
    for(size_t j=0; j<i; j++){
        printf("%c\n",array[j]);
    }

    // do not forget to put your toys away
    fclose(fp);

    // Simply return `array`
    // return &array;
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> return a pointer to that array

No, you don't have to do that.

You can write your prototype as `void layer4(char array[])` and modify the `array` directly - the change you made to `array` inside `layer4` will retain after that function exits.

Answer (score 2):

`array` is already pointer to `char`. So you need only to return `array`, not `&array`.

See this post [Arrays decaying into pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378555/arrays-decaying-into-pointers).

Answer (score 0):

`array` is already a pointer. So just do: `return array;`

Answer (score 0):

Your method should take the array as an array or as a pointer, as it is a pointer, then you can just return it as itself. [*try here*](http://ideone.com/NqbZ7f)

```
char* layer4(char array[])
{
    ..

    return array;
}
```